# Word for Success + Triumph

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Are there words that mean succeed and nurture, kind of like triumph and foster together?  Looking for something that conveys a winning environment that helps people achieve their goals. Halcyon is the placeholder, but feels too soft.

Comment: You need to give a bit more context if you want useful answers.  For instance, the suggestion of "incubator" only works in a *very* narrow sense.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding “something that conveys a winning environment that helps people achieve their goals”, *[incubator](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incubator)* has senses that may apply, including “(business) A support programme for the development of entrepreneurial companies”.

Phrase *[Center of Excellence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_excellence)* may be relevant:

> A center of excellence refers to a team, a shared facility or an entity that provides leadership, evangelization, best practices, research, support and/or training for a focus area. The focus area in this case might be a technology..., a business concept..., a skill... or a broad area of study...

Answer (score 0):

Incubator

This is used for an environment that promotes the growth of start up companies and helps them succeed in their Research, Development and Marketing efforts.  It starts from the nuture metaphor and has success as its aim. (So you've had three people mention this one now.)

Flagship

This uses a sailing rather than a nurture metaphor, but has the idea of recognized success and a focus for support (when applied to a project or centre).

The given *succeed* and *nurture* are verbs; also *triumph* and *foster* are verbs; although one in each pair is a noun - the suggestions made so far are all nouns. So consider

Incubate
Promote
Mature
Exalt
Seed

If these aren't the kind of things you are looking for some further info would be helpful.